# A problem occurs during the creation of a database in Odoo 12

Tags: postgresql, odoo, psql, odoo-12, postgresql-14

When I create a database, this problem appears:
Database creation error: relation "ir_model" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM ir_model WHERE state='manual' ^

I encountered this error with Odoo 12, even though I followed the same installation steps that worked fine for Odoo 15

[image]

[image: command line arguments]

INFO odoo12 odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'user=odoo12 password=xxx dbname=odoo12 host=localhost port=5432 sslmode=prefer'
INFO odoo12 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2024 09:22:58] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 - 13 0.010 1.595